# MySql complains about 'Duplicate entry' though unique data is being entered

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have this table in a mysql database:

```
mysql> show columns from wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm;
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| wifi_network_config_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| auth_algorithm         | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table was created using liquibase. Table creation itself does not define primary keys. Following table creation, the following liquibase command is used to set the combination of 2 columns as the primary key:

```
<addPrimaryKey tableName="wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm"
        columnNames="wifi_network_config_id,auth_algorithm"
        constraintName="pk_wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm"/>
```

Now, when you execute this to load data into this table:

```
LOCK TABLES `wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm` VALUES
(1, 'OPEN'),
(1, 'SHARED'),
(2, 'SHARED'),
(2, 'LEAP');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

You get:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 2
```

Since the combination of both columns is the primary key, so the combination of the data in the two columns should be unique - which is true for the data shown above. Why is mysql complaining?

Also, it's complaining that the value '1' is being assigned to key 2, which does not make sense. I changed the INSERT to:

```
INSERT INTO `wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm` (`wifi_network_config_id`, `auth_algorithm`)
```

but it did not make any difference - same complaint from mysql.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Can you confirm it created the table as you expected by running a 'SHOW CREATE TABLE wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm' ?

Comment: Thanks for this command - didn't know it was there. It showed the cause. After creating the table I was creating an index on wifi_network_config_id and had said it was unique.

Comment: After setting uniqe=false it works fine. Here is the command that had the problem: "CREATE TABLE `wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm` (
  `wifi_network_config_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `auth_algorithm` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`wifi_network_config_id`,`auth_algorithm`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_wifi_network_config_id` (`wifi_network_config_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm_wifi_network_config_id` FOREIGN KEY (`wifi_network_config_id`) REFERENCES `wifi_network_config` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue with @kbenson's help. The answer is in the comments for the original question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Is the table empty or missing these values before you execute the insert statement?

If I run this example twice I get an error message:

> Duplicate entry '1-OPEN' for key 'PRIMARY'

Calling `DELETE FROM wifi_network_config_auth_algorithm` first avoids that.

Otherwise there must be something wrong with the way the primary key was created, since your error message differs.

I created a test table using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
          `wifi` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `auth` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`wifi`,`auth`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try it. Please see the comments on the original post.

Comment: You should post what worked as an answer to your question rather than a comment, then you can select it as the correct answer, and it will serve to help future visitors with the same or similar problem.